# Sshfs or its substitute in Apple products?

Tags: ssh, unix

I instructs my Apple friend to get Sshfs, i.e. to mount an outside target, to home -directory but he cannot find sshfs for Mac. Dose there exist some substitute or some Apple-compiled version for Sshfs? If it exists, how can my friend install it?

Comment: ...perhaps some of them [here](http://howto.blbosti.com/2010/09/mount-a-remote-ssh-folder-in-ubuntu-cmd-and-gui/), some GUI -software a bit like Sshfs.

Answer (score 3):

You can get sshfs with [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/). Just download macports and run

```
sudo port install sshfs
```

in a terminal window.

Comment: Do you know whether some GUI alternative exists for Sshfs? I am not sure whether my friend is able to use sshfs, perhaps liking some ready GUI tool also. Anyway +1 -- if I can remember right, you need to install the Xtool or Xkey -something from developer -CD to get MacPorts running, right? Any idea whether it is possible to get MacPorts without the CD?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know a GUI for sshfs. Typically, you need XCode for macports – but you can get that from the App store. Still, it is not really easy for the computer semiliterate.

Comment: There should be a GUI here <https://code.google.com/p/macfuse/wiki/MACFUSE_FS_SSHFS>

Answer (score 0):

Harald suggested a package-installer but some alerts: package-installers such as MacPorts and Homebrew have problems such as old packages and broken packages. For example, the Homebrew's Sshfs is broken at the time of writing. Examples of package-installers include [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) and  [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

In the case of sshfs the problem is that it relies on [MacFuse/osxfuse](https://osxfuse.github.io/) which is not now open source so can't be built on Macports and [Homebrew has removed the ports from core](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/1760#discussioncomment-945235)

It is better to find the newest installation so you won't face odd errors. For example, the Sshfs -development files are [here](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/SSHFS) and the packages [here](https://github.com/osxfuse/sshfs/downloads).

Answer (score 0):

ABSOLUTELY!!! You don't need MacPorts, or Homebrew, or Cocoa.

MacFuse + MacFusion will do it.

If you want to mount an OS X drive through SSHFS from another computer on the network, you only need to enable Remote Login on OS X.